# A password, but not the right one?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, password

This is a bit strange. I have two computer. One where the OS is Ubuntu and the other where it is a Windows 10 VM. From the first computer, I SSH my VM and I got this

```
jeremie@jeremie-ThinkStation-D30:~$ ssh 192.168.x.x
The authenticity of host '192.168.x.x (192.168.x.x)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:4OuK3XcaFN5whW9exSrOYb8nnom+dqGt8DyF6Yjg5V0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.x.x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
jeremie@192.168.x.x's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
jeremie@192.168.x.x's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
jeremie@192.168.x.x's password: 
jeremie@192.168.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Be aware that I installed Bash/Ubuntu on my Windows VM. I had to set a username and password.

Why am I getting a rejection even though I enter the right password? Where is my error?

**UPDATE**

If I try with the same computer, i.e. my VM is hosted, I get the same problem using the same keyboard.

Comment: The only way you would get this error is from entering the wrong password.  Perhaps you made a mistake when originally setting up the password?  Or perhaps you have caps-lock on?  It's also possible that another keyboard layout was being used when you set up the password vs whatever keyboard layout you are currently using.  If you are in a different locale than EN-US you should try changing the keyboard layout when entering the password.

Comment: If I try on the same computer using the same keyboard, I have the exact same problem

Comment: Are you giving it username@IP address? Might be causing an issue if it's defaulting to a different account.

Comment: I'm talking about the keyboard *layout* not the keyboard itself.  An example of this would be having the [french keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) selected when the password was created.  This could have been an accidental selection, or it could have been automatically selected (this is especially true if you live somewhere other than the US).  In this example, if you had typed "snappylinux" as your password, it would have actually been entered as "snqppylinux"

Comment: I can certainly change my password and username so that it won't change anything. What do you suggest?

Comment: how are you changing the password without knowing the current password?  Wouldn't this solve your problem?

Comment: I can change the password directly in Win10 VM. I figure that certain characters are safe to be used

Comment: @Nmath I am trying to SSH that VM. I know well how to log into that VM and change username and password.